# Seperate integer into character PHP

Tags: php, sql

i try to make scoresheet where $row["first"]=756987
show Math 7, Biology 5, Sport 6, Sociology 9, Chemist 8, English 7 but it keep showing all 7
can someone help solve this and show some example
appreciate your help

```
foreach (str_split($row["first"]) as $v){}
echo "<table>
<tr><th colspan='2'>Score </th></tr>
<tbody class='tbody'>
        <tr>
            <td>Math" . $v. "</td>
            <td>Biology" .$v "</td>
            <td>Sport" . $v. "</td>
            <td>Sociology" . $v. "</td>
            <td>Chemist" . $v. "</td>
            <td>English" . $v. "</td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: This seems to be database related; am I right? If so, the issue could be in your db and/or the way you're querying.

Comment: yeah it's database thing get the number from $first

Comment: Btw, why isn't your table code not inside the `{}`?

Comment: FYI foreach loop is not traversed in your code

Comment: yeah i just realized it thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\str_split()` and `list()` method for your use case, example below:

```
$row["first"]=756987;
list($math, $bio, $sport, $socio, $chemist, $english) = \str_split($row["first"]);
echo "<table>
<tr><th colspan='2'>Score </th></tr>
<tbody class='tbody'>
        <tr>
            <td>Math " . $math. "</td>
            <td>Biology " .$bio. "</td>
            <td>Sport " . $sport. "</td>
            <td>Sociology " . $socio. "</td>
            <td>Chemist " . $chemist. "</td>
            <td>English " . $english. "</td>
        </tr>
</tbody>";
```

Docs

**list() :**  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php

**str_split() :** https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split

Answer (score 2):

```
$subjects=['Math','Biology','Sport','Sociology','Chemist','English'];
$row["first"]=756987;
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><th colspan='2'>Score </th></tr>";
echo "<tbody class='tbody'>";
echo "<tr>";

    $index=0;
    foreach (str_split($row["first"]) as $v){
        echo "<td>". $subjects[$index] ."-". $v. "</td>";
        $index++;
    } 
echo "</tr>";
echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: This is a more extensive rebuild than my answer, but it's more maintainable too. +1

Answer (score 0):

You loop through all the digits at once:

```
foreach (str_split($row["first"]) as $v){}
                                        ^^-- these two brackets here.
```

and then show the whole table using the last value of `$v`, always the same.

Do instead:

```
$v = str_split($row["first"]); // Now $v is an *array*, not a single digit
echo "<table>
<tr><th colspan='2'>Score </th></tr>
<tbody class='tbody'>
    <tr>
        <td>Math {$v[0]}</td>
        <td>Biology {$v[1]}</td>
        <td>Sport {$v[2]}</td>
        <td>Sociology {$v[3]}</td>
        <td>Chemist {$v[4]}</td>
        <td>English {$v[5]}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>";
```

(actually now that I look at it, you probably also wanted to write two separate cells - `<td>English</td><td>{$v[5]}</td>`, not  `<td>English {$v[5]}</td>`)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `foreach`.  Just do something like this in your table:

```
print vsprintf("<tr><td>Math %s</td>
                <td>Biology %s</td>
                <td>Sport %s</td>
                <td>Sociology %s</td>
                <td>Chemist %s</td>
                <td>English %s</td></tr>",
                str_split($row["first"]);
```